# How to fetch data using inner queries using parse in Android?

Tags: android, mysql, parse-platform

I have 3 classes in Parse.

1)Post (post_id,post_text,user_pointer)

2)Votes (vote_type,post_pointer,user_pointer)

3)Comments (comment_id,post_pointer,user_pointer)

I Need to fetch list of post texts, total count of votes & comments for a particular post 
and check whether the current user has voted. If voted, return the vote_type(upvote, downvote) as well.

I tried this.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Post");

        query.orderByDescending("createdAt"); 
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() 
        {
          @Override 
          public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) 
          {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e==null)
            {
              if(list!=null)
              {
                for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
                {
                    final PostObject obj = new PostObject();
                    String posttext = list.get(i).getString("post_text");

                    obj.setPost(posttext);
                    obj.setObjectID(objID);

                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Votes");
                    ParseObject pointerObj = ParseObject.createWithoutData("Post",obj.getObjectID()); 
                    query.whereEqualTo("post_pointer", pointerObj); 

                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() 
                            {

                                @Override
                                public void done(List<ParseObject> arg0, ParseException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    if(e==null)
                                    {
                                        if(arg0.size()>0)
                                        {
                                           // get votes count 
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {

                                    }
                                }
                    });


                }
```

But the for loop doesn't wait for the inner query to execute. Can someone suggest a good approach to write a query in my case.

Comment: Sorry I'm slightly confused so can you explain something to me. You say you want to current user has voted but there is no userId column in your votes so how do you expect to know if the user has voted?

Comment: @JayDev I have a pointer to Post, there I have userId column.

Comment: But surely that means that every vote on the same post has the same userID?

Comment: @JayDev Forgot to mention. I have User pointer also as a column in Votes table.

Comment: Ah ok that makes more sense. So I am assuming the whole reason for this query is to find out whether the current user has voted incase he tries to vote again?

Comment: I only ask because I think you are going about the query the wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used for each loop instead of for loop. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try replacing  obj.getObjectID()  with obj.getObjectId()

Comment: Prob is for loop exit, that was just a typo.

Comment: as u mentioned "But the for loop doesn't wait for the inner query to execute" inner query 'query.findInBackground' is not getting executed because line 'query.whereEqualTo("post_pointer", pointerObj)' pointerObj value is initialization using "obj.getObjectID() " so there is a typo which is giving may be null value or other value which is not equal to any pointer value in Votes Class(query.whereEqualTo("post_pointer", pointerObj))

Comment: i am not sure but check this line " obj.setObjectID(objID);" for typo where objID is not initialized any where in the code